# Save to cassandra in spark, parallelize method is not availble in java

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to save one row only to a cassandra table using spark in java (this comes as a result after long processing in spark), I am using the new method to connect to cassandra using spark session as follows:

```
     SparkSession spark = SparkSession
          .builder()
          .appName("App")
          .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "cassandra1.example.com")
          .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
          .master("spark://cassandra.example.com:7077")
          .getOrCreate();
```

The connection is successful and works well as I have Spark installed on the same nodes as cassandra, after reading some RDDs from cassandra I want to save to another table in cassandra, so I am following the documentation [here](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/7_java_api.md), namely, the part to save to cassandra as follows:

```
List<Person> people = Arrays.asList(
    new Person(1, "John", new Date()),
    new Person(2, "Troy", new Date()),
    new Person(3, "Andrew", new Date())
);
JavaRDD<Person> rdd = spark.sparkContext().parallelize(people);
javaFunctions(rdd).writerBuilder("ks", "people", mapToRow(Person.class)).saveToCassandra();
```

The problem which I am facing is that parallelize method is not accepted, and only a scala version looks avaiable, the error is:

```
The method parallelize(Seq<T>, int, ClassTag<T>) in the type 
SparkContext is not applicable for the arguments (List<Person>)
```

How can I use that in Java to save to cassandra table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `parallelize` `java.util.List` you can use `JavaSparkContext` (not `SparkContext`) , something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;

JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());
sc.parallelize(people);
```